# New Web Application only works using default settings

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection, web-application, windows-server, dns

I've been trying to create a web application and site collection using intranet.contoso.com. However after the webapp and site collections have been successfully created, the site won't display. I've made sure to add the DNS entry, I've added te ip (10.0.0.21) and host name "intranet.contoso.com" to the server host file, i've flushed the dns, nothing works. I've been told it's an issue with DNS mapping but i'm not sure how to fix it. I've disabled backloopchecking also.

Basically I can only access sites using the default values but when i try to give my site an actual name, host header and ect, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how these Url, DNS and web server works.

protocol://server-name.domain-name/directory/filename

http://www.hennigweb.com/projects/webclass/urls.html

Now in your case contoso.com is not your server name. As you are working on local you need to know the name of that server. contoso.com must be replaced by that name.

But if you have a live domain you can use it. I you want any other url to be assigned for your web app then you need to amke an entry into the Host file on your server which you could find at..C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc